# Will an application be rejected from the App Store if Xcode shows warnings for it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

If I build my iPhone application and Xcode shows compile-time warnings, will it be rejected if I submit it to the App Store?

Comment: don't worry they wont reject your app just for warnings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What types of warnings? Every warning you have can be fixed with proper coding.

I ask because while the warnings themselves may not get your app rejected, but crashing, bad memory management that results in the app eating up lots of memory and not releasing it (resulting in a crash eventually), or the app just not functioning as described will get it rejected.

Do you not want to fix the problems to ensure your app runs well, gets good ratings due to satisfied customers, and therefor sells well?

Comment: Warnings in Objective-C tend to be more serious than elsewhere, such as when messages are being sent to objects that don't respond to them.  This is why I always build my projects with the `Treat Warnings as Errors` option enabled.

Comment: So for example I am using a MoPub ad framework SDK and that SDK when used in Swift 4 shows a bunch of warnings. Fixing those  is beyond my control. The app itself and the ads served by Mopub works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Apple is not gonna reject the application because of warning. But be sure that you haven't used any Private API. If possible remove the warning. It is not a difficult task for you. If you can develop application than why you can't make it warning free ?

Answer (score 1):

These warnings won't show up when you use the app. 
They are just hints of XCode to tell you that they could be problematic.

You only need to be sure that the warnings don't produce a crash. If so Apple will reject your App.